# Learning about space spanned by matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, self-learning

I am looking for books/papers/chapters that deal with space $\mathcal{S}$ containing MATRICES. $\mathcal{S}$ satisfies

1. **Addition:** If $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B} \in \mathcal{S}$ then $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B} \in \mathcal{S}$
2. **Scalar Multiplication:** If $\mathbf{A}\in \mathcal{S}$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$ then $k\mathbf{A} \in \mathcal{S}$

I found questions like [Determining Bases of Space Spanned by (perhaps) Infinitely Many Matrix.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493021/determining-bases-of-space-spanned-by-perhaps-infinitely-many-matrix) and [Space spanned by matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406106/space-spanned-by-matrices) helpful in getting an intuition but I am looking for more formal/rigorous treatment of this topic.

Comment: You can create a natural isomorphism from the space of $m \times n$ matrices to $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$. I mean, in all honesty, there isn't really much. You're just looking at a vector space, except your vectors aren't the ones you're used to.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are just looking for a number of diverse examples of vector spaces, you are probably trying to learn about spaces (and algebras) of *linear operators* on vector spaces.  (The concept of a linear operator has an invariant--i.e., coordinate-independent definition; that of a matrix, does not.)

Spaces of linear operators on finite-dimensional spaces are finite-dimensional themselves, so their properties are the properties shared by all finite-dimensional vector spaces (whatever plays the role of the individual vector).  If you are looking to learn about these, I recommend Halmos's *Finite-dimensional vector spaces* and *Linear algebra problem book*.

It gets a lot more interesting and challenging when you get into linear operators on (infinite-dimensional) Banach spaces: here, the algebra is intertwined with the topology.  If you are new to this, I recommend, first, becoming acquainted with *representation theory* (the first 60 pages of Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups* will do), and then operator algebras (to get a flavor, look through http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183510397, and then visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra)

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I am dealing with finite-dimensional elements (vectors in Rn and matrices in Rnxm) so I will look into first reference.